# UIWebView - Read content from file and delete the file

Tags: ios, ios5

I have downloaded some content and store it in a file. While it was writing in the file, I will encrypt the file content. Now I have to show the decrypted file content in `UIWebView`.  So , What I have done, I will decrypt the content and store it file.

Using `loadRequest` I can the content in `UIWeView`. Now again , I have to encrypt the content. How to do THIS? When will I come to know the `loadRequest` is finished without using `UIWebView` Delegate method (`webviewDidFinishLoad`)?

Is there and guidance on how this cane be done? Is even it possible to do it? I would appreciate any suggestions or some other way to do this.

Comment: the same way u encrypted early and in webviewDidFinishLoad your encryption starts.

Comment: Any reason you want to do this without using delegate methods?

Comment: yes it correct Prince....     But I dont want to use webViewDidFinishLoad. is it possible ?

Comment: Hi lostInTransit.. My encryption and decryption behind in my dylip. so I could not check my client have used delegate or not in their code.

Answer (score 0):

I think it does not have the direct way to solve this issue. So, I have manually removed the file from the document directory after some time using the afterDelay method.